# В чем отличие RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()) от RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

при создании Retrofit использую

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
```

В некоторых туториал пишут, что нужно использовать

```
addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
```

Подскажите, в чём отличие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из официальной документации

```
createWithScheduler(io.reactivex.Scheduler scheduler)
Returns an instance which creates synchronous observables that subscribe on scheduler 
by default.
```

То есть все ваши запросы по умолчанию будет выполняться в этом планировщике. В вашем случае на `Schedulers.io()`

Comment: Что значит по умолчанию? Я правильно понимаю, что в этом случае я могу отказаться от использования subscribeOn(Scheduler.io) ?

Comment: Да вы можете  отказаться от использования subscribeOn(Scheduler.io)

Comment: теперь понятно, большое спасибо